# Python KeyError with Curly Braces

Tags: python

I want Python to run system commands of curl where I pass in some arguments. I want to also use `-w "%{http_code}"` to return the HTTP status code of the result (i.e. `200`, `302`, etc)

The command I currently have is

```
print os.popen('curl "{0}" -L -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}"'.format("http://google.com")).read()
```

but this returns `KeyError: 'http_code'` and I presume its because the `http_code` is wrapped by curlybraces. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just double up the curly braces when passing to `.format`:

```
'curl "{0}" -L -o /dev/null -s -w "%{{http_code}}"'.format("http://google.com")
```

This escapes them and will produce `%{http_code}` in the resulting string.